# placing balls in bins

Tags: probability

> Suppose we have $n$ balls and $m$ bins. Then it's well-know that the probability that bin $i$ has exactly $k$ balls is $P_k=\binom{n}{k} \space (\frac{1}{m})^k \space (\frac{m-1}{m})^{n-k}$.

Suppose now we want to find the probability that bin $i$ has at least two balls:

On one hand, by the above it is: $P_{\ge2}=1-P_0-P_1=1-(\frac{m-1}{m})^{n}-n\space(\frac{1}{m}) \space (\frac{m-1}{m})^{n-1}$

On the other hand, it would make sense to be $P_{\ge2}=\binom{n}{2} \space (\frac{1}{m})^2$ (i.e. the probability of putting two balls in it without taking into account what happens to the other $n-2$ balls).

I don't understand what's wrong with the second probability and why the two equations don't agree.

Comment: The second method overcounts.  If balls $A,B,C$ are in the specified urn, you count it $3$ times (once as the pair $A,B$, once as the pair $A,C$, and again as the pair $B,C$).

Comment: Just to stress, your expression isn't even bounded by $1$.